# Kibana not showing some of the documents from elasticsearch - even though they exist

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have an elasticsearch and kibana setup, I'm sending documents to elasticsearch and I get back a 201 created, when I query the id of the document directly (curl to the elasticsearch API) I get back the result:

```
# curl elasticsearch.metrics:9200/falco/_doc/1559716938212262231-1
{"_index":"falco","_type":"_doc","_id":"1559716938212262231-1","_version":1,"_seq_no":1096,"_primary_term":1,"found":true,"_source":{ "priority": "Info", "output": "test", "rule": "test", "output_fields": { "test": "test", "evt.time": "1559716938212262231" }}}
```

However, this document (and many others) does not appear in kibana.

That's not to say that nothing appears in kibana, I do see some of the documents there, even documents newer than my test appear.

Why might that be?

Comment: can you post `mapping` and also the document that has `1559716938212262231-1` ?

Comment: the document with the id is what I pasted in my question (that's the entire document, it's very short ;-) ). How do I get the mapping?

Comment: Also, I did notice that my test document has no time field, could that have anything to do with it?

Comment: ok. to get mapping try `curl elasticsearch.metrics:9200/falco/_mapping`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to display documents in the diacovery tab for example, kibana narrows down to all documents within the selected time range in the time picker (upper right corner). You also have a index pattern selected, which have a time field defined (@timestamp in most of the cases).

So Kibana searches for documents with a value within the selected time range in the configured time field for the currently selected index pattern.

If you data lacks in a @timestamp field you can easily create a different index pattern using a different date field present in all of you docs. If there's none, conisider enriching your documents with such one.

Comment: This helped me.  I deleted the index pattern under "Stack Management" -> "Index Management", recreated the index without the @timestamp field, and my records showed up.  You can tell if you have it set when in "Discover", because it will show a time filter.  I spent more time on this than I want to admit, but it's working now.  Thanks!